Is every bounded complex valued harmonic function on the open unit disc a sum of bounded holomorphic function and bounded antiholomorphic function?
Let $\varphi$ be a bounded complex valued harmonic function on the open unit disc. Then $\varphi = \psi + \bar \chi$ for some holomorphic functions $\psi, \chi$ on the open unit disc (see last line of the question for the decomposition). Is it necessarily the case that $\psi$ and $\chi$ are bounded?
I am almost sure that this is false, however, I have not been able to find a counterexample yet. Is there any immediate counterexample for this?
Any bounded harmonic function can be written as $\varphi (z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} c_n z^n + \sum_{n>0} c_{-n} \bar {z} ^n$ for each $z \in \mathbb D$. Take $\psi (z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} c_n z^n $ and $\chi (z) =\sum_{n>0} \bar c_{-n} {z} ^n$ for $z\in \mathbb D$. Are $\psi$ and $\chi$ bounded?

Perhaps you can manipulate with ${\rm Im}(\log(1+z))$

@RyszardSzwarc  I do not see it. Why $\Im \log (1+z)$?

$\arg(1+z)$ is bounded and harmonic, and is the real part of $-i \log(1+z)$, which is not bounded in the unit disk.

There are general results that show how "bounded" or "integrable" (bounded is the limit of highly integrable on the circle) holomorphic $\psi$ can be when $\Re \psi =\phi$ is such and in general the answer is same except at the two ends of this type of behavior (bounded or just integrable) when $\psi$ can fall a little short - here for example if $\phi$ bounded then $\psi$ is in any $L^p$ of the unit circle for finite $p$ but not necessarily bounded so not in $L^{\infty}$

Let $\varphi(z) = \arg(1+z)$ with the principal value of the argument. $\varphi$ is harmonic in the unit disk and bounded: $|\varphi(z)| < \pi/2$.
Also $\varphi(z) = \operatorname{Re}f(z)$ with $f(z) = i \log(1+z)$ which is not bounded.
It is not difficult to see that if
$$
 \varphi(z) = \frac 12 \bigl(f(z) + \overline{f(z)}\bigr) = \psi(z) + \overline{\chi(z)}
$$
with holomorphic functions $\psi$ and $\chi$ then these functions differ from $f/2$ by at most a constant, so both functions are necessarily unbounded.
